# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "locations_location" does not exist during migrate

Tags: django

I created a custom app, locations, for my project. I don't know what, but something got messed up along the way in setup. I removed all migrations and deleted everything from the db for this app to start fresh and I'm still getting an error when I try to do the initial migrate after creating the tables. Is something wrong with my model? I don't understand the error.

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Map(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Phone Number")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Email Address")
    # manager = models.ForeignKey(Staff,related_name='+')
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(Staff)
    map = models.ForeignKey(Map, null=True)
```

Stack trace:

```
Applying locations.0013_auto_20170405_0934...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build//clientname/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 121, in database_forwards
schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 438, in remove_field
self.execute(sql)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "locations_location" does not exist

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help you. Please show the full traceback, and the migration file which is failing.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated it.

Comment: That shows that the problem is occurring when running migration `0013_auto_20170405_0934`, but you haven't shown the migration file. It doesn't seem like you removed all the migration files for the `locations` app if you already have 13 migrations.

Comment: @Alasdair Even when I delete all the migration files and make the initial migration and showmigrations, it shows up as  [X] 0001_initial like it's already been migrated. I can't figure out how to clear it out so I can start 100% all over. I've done the --fake migration and still no luck. So it wont recreate the tables because it thinks the migration already happened.

Comment: You can do `python manage.py migrate locations zero` to undo all the migrations for the app. If you have removed all the tables from the db, you can use the fake option as well: `python manage.py migrate locations zero --fake`